# this pattern-matching is not exhaustive. Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

can someone tell me why does this code`# let func [g] a = g a ::[] ;;`

output this warning

> Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
>   Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
>   []

Answer (score 3):

The argument `[g]` will match a single-element list, and bind that element to `g`. `func [f] a` will work, but what if the function is applied with an empty list, `func [] a`, or a list with multiple elements, `func [f, g] a`? What *can* it do other than raise an exception? That's what the warning is telling you.

Comment: do you have an idea on how to get rid of the warning ?

Comment: what should happen if you call `func [] 0` ?

Comment: The proper way is of course to deal with it appropriately through a `match`: `let func gs a = match gs with [g] -> ... | _ -> ...`. Otherwise if you're on 4.06 you can use the `[@warning]` attribute, or if you're on an older version the `-w` compiler switch, with `-8`. But if you really only want a single element, why are you taking a list at all?

Comment: it's just an assignment i needed to get (a->b)list -> a ->b list so i used this one